# How to disable scientific notation while debugging in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, scientific-notation

How can I turn off the (annoying) scientific notation for numbers while debugging in Android Studio 3?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can evaluate expression in dialog with bellow code:

```
double value = 2.46464646464464E11;
```

just open dialog (only in debug mode) of evaluate expression (Alt + f8) and write

```
 new BigDecimal(value);
```

Look below screenshot:
[image]

Comment: This is.. not fast.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to string and print/debug.